# How to match a string to the device time

Tags: android, json

When my device time is between or equal to the starting time and ending time, I want it to  show me `ChogadiaName`. This is my method where I'm fetching the time:

```
/*{"chogadia":[{"ChogadiaName":1,"StartTime":"5:31:19 AM","EndTime":"7:14:15 AM","Effect":"Inauspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":3,"StartTime":"8:57:10 AM","EndTime":"10:40:5 AM","Effect":"Auspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":4,"StartTime":"10:40:5 AM","EndTime":"12:22:59 AM","Effect":"Auspicious Chogadia"}]}*/

public class ChogadiaParser {

public static  ArrayList<Chogadia> mList=new ArrayList<Chogadia>();
public static Chogadia mChogadia;
public static String response,chogadia;
public static String Lucky="Auspicious Chogadia";
public static String UnLucky="Inauspicious Chogadia";


public static void GroupResult(String url){

    try{
      JSONArray jArray;
      JSONObject jObject;

     response=GetJsonObject.sendRequest(url);

     if(response == null){
            return;
        }

     jObject=new JSONObject(response);
     jArray=jObject.getJSONArray("chogadia");
     mList.clear();
     for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

         mChogadia=new Chogadia();
         jObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         mChogadia.SetChogadiaName(jObject.getString("ChogadiaName"));
         mChogadia.SetStartTime(jObject.getString("StartTime"));
         mChogadia.SetEndTime(jObject.getString("EndTime"));
         mChogadia.SetEffect(jObject.getString("Effect"));
         mList.add(mChogadia);



         if(mathcTime(jObject.getString("StartTime"),jObject.getString("EndTime"))){


             System.out.println("Matched Name Is: " + jObject.getString("ChogadiaName"));

             break; // break loop
         }



     } 


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



private static boolean mathcTime(String stime,String eTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date ct = new Date();
        Date st = ft.parse(stime);
        Date et=ft.parse(eTime);;

        long currentTime = ((ct.getHours()*60)*60) + (ct.getMinutes()*60) + (ct.getSeconds());
        long startTime = ((st.getHours()*60)*60) + (st.getMinutes()*60) + (st.getSeconds());
        long endTime = ((et.getHours()*60)*60) + (et.getMinutes()*60) + (et.getSeconds());

        if(currentTime>=startTime || currentTime<=endTime){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
 return false;
}
}
```

Comment: @Scott W-Can u help me for this code..

Answer (score 0):

You should use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

```
The TimerTask class represents a task to run at a specified time. The task may be run once or repeatedly.
```

Or you can use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which watches [Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK). Android will beam Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK every minute. Then you can catch that in receiver and do what you want.

```
Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by exlicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().
```

Also, what in your code

```
currentTime>=startTime || currentTime<=endTime
```

should be

```
currentTime>=startTime && currentTime<=endTime
```

Comment: -My prblm is how to match time when application is open and show Chogadia name....

Comment: -i have both of condition but not given the exact output

Comment: No, `currentTime>=startTime || currentTime<=endTime` is always return true as `startTime < endTime`, so you need to use `currentTime>=startTime && currentTime<=endTime`

Comment: Math is useful. Just draw a number axis, put startTime and endTime in it with your inequation region, you can see everything clearly.

Comment: -code is working but now new prblm. i have faced it match only PM time after or start with 12 PM. it not match the time AM Time like 9 AM to 11 AM

Comment: Using `HH:mm:ss` instead of `hh:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will return true/false, if the Tablet time is greater than ServerTime (5 mins)

```
    if ((serverDate.getTime() >= tabletDate.getTime() - 300000) &&
    (serverDate.getTime() <= tabletDate.getTime() + 300000)) 
        {
         isTrue = true;
            } else { 
                    isTrue = false;
                }
```

Comment: @Kalai.G-How to check AM|PM in this its AM OR PM.

Comment: Wether you need to check tablets time or server time?